# ConcurrentLinkedDeque vs ArrayDeque

Tags: java, deque, arraydeque

I know the basic difference between two of them that ConcurrentLinkedDeque can be use in multithreaded application.

Can any one give me practical example how it would affect the performance of application if wrongly used, in which scenario i should go with ConcurrentLinkedDeque and when to use ArrayDeque.

Answer (score 5):

Use `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` if you need synchronized access to your queue from multiple threads, `ArrayDeque` if not.

Period.

The consequence of using the wrong one is that if you attempt to access an `ArrayDeque` in a multi-thread setting you will corrupt your queue.

Period.

That is your only performance consideration.  All others are moot.

Unless...

You ran your application through a profiler and discovered most of its time is spent inside of `ConcurrentLinkedDeque.size()`. Then switch to `ArrayDeque` wrapped in `synchronized` blocks.

End of lecture ;)

Comment: How it will corrupt my deque ArrayDeque if i use in multi-thread application?

Comment: `ArrayDeque` does not provide the thread synchronization necessary to ensure that multiple threads do not simultaneously try to access it.  Imagine, for example, thread "A" trying to do `addFirst()` while thread "B", _at the same time_, is trying to do `removeFirst()`.  The would conflict with each other and possibly leave the `ArrayQueue` in a confused state.

Comment: ConcurrentLinkedDeque does not provide synchronization. If you Ctrl-F the class and its superclasses you won't find any use of locks or synchronized statements. It uses compreAndSwap from sun.misc.Unsafe.